# Simple rspec model test failing to test if attribute is set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am relatively new to rails, and I am not sure why this rspec test is failing.

Model class

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User"

  before_create :generate_token

  private 
  def generate_token
    self.token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)
  end
end
```

Test

```
  it "should create a hash for the token" do
    invitation = Invitation.new
    Digest::SHA1.stub(:hexdigest).and_return("some random hash")
    invitation.token.should == "some random hash"
  end
```

Error:

```
Failure/Error: invitation.token.should == "some random hash"
       expected: "some random hash"
            got: nil (using ==)
```

The invitation model has a token:string attribute. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`before_create` runs before `save` on new objects. All `Invitation.new` does is instantiate a new invitation object. You need to either save after you call new or just create the invitation object to begin with.

```
Digest::SHA1.stub(:hexdigest).and_return("some random hash")
invitation = Invitation.new
invitation.save
invitation.token.should == "some random hash"
```

or

```
Digest::SHA1.stub(:hexdigest).and_return("some random hash")
invitation = Invitation.create
invitation.token.should == "some random hash"
```

Comment: Did you stub it before you saved/created the invitation?